# Terminology for discrete subgroups of PSL(2,k), where k is a non-archimedean local field

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, terminology, non-archimedean-fields

$\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$I'm asking about terminology for discrete subgroups of $\PSL(2,k)$, where $k$ is a non-archimedean local field.
As it is rather clumsy to have to use such expressions many times in a paper, I would like to use short meaningful terminology which is easy to remember.

My question is two-fold

1. Is anyone aware of existing terminology?
2. If there is no known existing terminology, I thought of using the following

a) $p$-adic Kleinian group for discrete subgroups of $\PSL(2,\mathbb{C}_p)$

b) $p$-adic Fuchsian group for discrete subgroups of $\PSL(2,k)$, where $k$ is a $p$-adic number field

c) Laurent group for discrete subgroups of $\PSL(2,k)$, where $k$ is field of formal Laurent series

d) non-Archimedean Kleinian group for discrete subgroups of $\PSL(2,k)$, where $k$ is a non-archimedean local field.

Any comments and suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: The meaning of "non-Archimedean local field" with which I am familiar embraces two of your other cases (as I understand them—I am not used to the terminology, but the obvious signification of "$p$-adic number field" seems to be "finite extension of $\mathbb Q_p$").  Are all $p$-adic Fuchsian groups, and all Laurent groups, also non-Archimedean Kleinian groups?

Comment: Yes, I indeed mean p-adic number field as finite extension of Qp, so d is the union of b and c, but then maybe a) is badly chosen, maybe I should take p-adic Kleinian group for case of p-adic number fields, p-adic Fuchsian group for case of PSL(2,Qp) itself and either not name a) or name it differently.